# Выравнивание блоков по центру страницы

Tags: html, вёрстка

Есть три блока div, их нужно выровнять по центру и по вертикали. Когда будет меняться размер окна, они должны так же пропорционально изменяться. Блоки имеют свойство 'float:left;'

Подскажите, как это можно реализовать.

Answer (score 1):

Ну зачем им `float:left`? Им не нужно это свойство. Да кто это придумал — блочные элементы прилеплять к другим блочным элементам с помощью обтекания? Когда же это закончится?!

Можно [так вот](http://jsfiddle.net/zJjqE/). Так — правильно с точки зрения отображения и удовлетворительно с точки зрения логики. Можно еще установить `display:inline-block`, но с точки зрения отображения будет неверно (точнее, сложно): придется устанавливать ширину каждого блока, контролировать, чтобы между ними не было пробелов, и решать еще несколько проблем. То есть, разметка станет очень требовательной, а css — перенасыщенным. Так что, лучше так, как я сделал в примере.